# How to make an image appear on a random position onclick

Tags: javascript, html

I'm pretty new to JavaScript and all I want to do is when you click on a button it will make an image appear in a random spot.

What I've tried:

```
 function show_image(src, width, height, alt) {
  var img = document.createElement("img");
  img.src = src;
  img.width = width;
  img.height = height;
  img.alt = alt;


  document.body.appendChild("imglink"); 
}
```

But that doesn't even make a new element.

Can someone tell me the correct code?

Comment: Do you want to display from a set of images? Or just a single one?

Comment: i want to display a single image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a little error in appendChild, you should append the created element instead. Other than that, simply set top and left to something random and you're ready to go

```js
function show_image(src, width, height, alt) {
  var img = document.createElement("img");
  img.src = src;
  img.width = width;
  img.height = height;
  img.alt = alt;
  
  // set the position
  img.style.position = 'absolute';
  img.style.top = document.body.clientHeight * Math.random() + 'px';
  img.style.left = document.body.clientWidth * Math.random() + 'px';

  document.body.appendChild(img);
}
document.getElementById('foo').addEventListener('click', () =>
  show_image("http://placekitten.com/200/300", 200, 300, 'foo')
);
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<button id="foo">
  Get a cat
</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem in the code you already have. The `appendChild` method takes an `HTMLElement`, not a `String`.

However, to execute a function on `click`, you have to add an eventlistener to the element you want to be clickable. The method to create/add eventlisteners is called `addEventListener`. It takes the name of the event as a string (`'click'` in this case), a `function` to execute and (optionally) a boolean value.

`<HTMLElement>.addEventListener('click', <Function>);`

To add a `click` eventlistener to the `<body>` element for example, you'd write:

```
document.body.addEventListener('click', function () { /* do something */ });
```

Now for the creation of the `<img>`:

Like you already do, the `createElement` function is typically used to create `HTMLElement` instances. It takes the tagname of the element you want to create and returns a new `HTMLElement`. To add properties to that element, you can usually do it by assigning values to the properties. Bear in mind that you have to assing `null` to *remove* a property.

This creates a new `<img>` element and assigns properties to it.

```
var myImg = document.createElement('img');
myImg.alt = 'A picture of Bill Murray';
myImg.src = 'https://www.fillmurray.com/400/300';
myImg.width = 400;
myImg.height = 300;
```

To add that image to the DOM, you use `appendChild`. For placing it into the `<body>` element:

```
document.body.appendChild(myImg);
```

This adds the `<img>` to the *end of the children of `<body>`*.

Although you now know how to place the new element into the DOM, it won't be placed *at a random position*. For this, you need a combination of `Math.random` and `innerWidth`/`innerHeight`. Alternatively, use `getBoundingClientRect`.

```
function getRandomCoordsIn (element) {
  var rect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
  // rect has 4 numeric properties: top, left, width, height
  // we return a pair of values which always is inside the element passed
  return [
    rect.top + Math.random() * rect.height, // top
    rect.left + Math.random() * rect.width  // left
  ];
}
```

Let's see what we can do with this:

```
document.body.addEventListener('click', handleClick);

function handleClick () {
  var coords = getRandomCoordsIn(document.body);

  var myImg = document.createElement('img');
  myImg.alt = 'A picture of Bill Murray';
  myImg.src = 'https://www.fillmurray.com/400/300';
  myImg.width = 400;
  myImg.height = 300;

  // This assigns inline CSS styles
  myImg.style.top = coords[0] + 'px';
  myImg.style.left = coords[1] + 'px';

  document.body.appendChild(myImg);
}

function getRandomCoordsIn (element) {
  var rect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
  // rect has some numeric properties, we need: top, left, width, height
  // we return a pair of coordinates which is located inside
  // the element passed
  return [
    rect.top + Math.random() * rect.height, // top
    rect.left + Math.random() * rect.width  // left
  ];
}
```

You'll also need some styles:

```
html { height: 100vh; overflow: auto; }
body { min-height: 100%; }
img { position: absolute; display: block; }
```